# Confusion regarding the Biot-Savart law

Tags: electromagnetism

I was reading about the Biot-Savart law and there were two formulas stated in the textbook.
One was stated as the Biot-Savart law

[image]

and the other was stated as the field due to a long, straight wire

[image]

My question is what is and why is there difference between two formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first formula is regarding the field created by a small arc length of a possibly-curved conductor. If we integrate that expression over the whole curve of the conductor, then we get the field at a point due to the conductor.

The second expression is the integrated version of the previous formula for an infinitely long straight wire. I wouldn't really consider the second to be the Biot-Savart law; rather it should be the field of a long straight conductor.

As an extra point, I'd like to say that it'd be much easier to find the field of a long straight wire conductor using Ampere's law rather than Biot-Savart.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a specialized form to spacecurves. The second is even more specialized: its for line shaped conductor.

Comment: An infinite line shaped conductor.